# Security Definer Functions vs Views for Row Level Security

Tags: postgresql

I am using [RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) in the `public` schema of a Postgresql 10 database. Sometimes I have the circumstance that the RLS policy needs to access the same table it was created on (due to the underlying application rights model) or I need to query the table for pure performance in an admin context, where the RLS rule is already fulfilled.

So to circument the infinite recursion (when the same table is used in the policy) and the performance reason I have created `views` and `security definer functions` over the time.

So for example the table `public.verbatims` has a view created by the table owner now:

```
CREATE VIEW private.verbatims_list AS (SELECT * FROM public.verbatims);
```

And a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION private.verbatims_list() RETURNS SETOF verbatims AS $$
  SELECT * FROM public.verbatims;
$$
STABLE
LANGUAGE SQL
SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Both do their job at the moment.

From what I gather from the Postgres documentation on views (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html, Notes section) and on functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html) - the concept is the same. The view/function is executed with the `owner` permission. So this should not make a difference for my use case.

However I want to refactor so that we only have either views with table owner rights - or security definer functions.

Is it fair to say, that both are equally functional for this use case or is there a difference I should be aware of? Using a function seems more "explicit" for what the use case is.

---

Updating the question with regards to possible optimization (from comments below) when using a View vs. Function.

Functions can be "inlined" under certain conditions:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions
- `The rules set out here are believed to be correct for pg versions between 8.4 and 9.5.`

Even though this article is pretty old - my tests show that a security definer function cannot be "inlined" (which makes sense I guess).

I have created a DB fiddle to demonstrate a simple test:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkWMitjcxHxX5wxmtoqfyB/4

When using the function `verbatims_list_security()` in a simple query, Postgres uses a function scan and not an index scan. My assumption here is, that using the index is "inlining".

Also from the comments: When using a view, is `WITH (security barrier)` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-privileges.html) necessary for my use case?

My current judgment would be: probably no. Since I use RLS for ensuring multitenancy and acl rights in an HTTP api and not for a datawarehouse and their users. I control which operators are passed to the underlying queries - and the views/functions are never exposed "directly".

Comment: I was wondering this myself, especially wrt. optimisation. I fear that the function, while being better to handle, cannot be as easily inlined; however I'm not certain about views (which would need to use [`security barrier`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-privileges.html)) being better in this regard.

Comment: @Bergi According to https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions `SETOF` returning functions marked as `security definer` cannot be inlined properly. This would indeed favor the view tactic. I have no experience with views marked as `security barrier` and it's importance, yet.

Comment: Me neither, that's the same page I found :-) I'm not sure how up-to-date the information is, though, or whether the optimisation (and its issues) of view inlining is just not documented as much.